# Authenticate ssh key via Cisco ACS (TACACS+)

Tags: ssh, tacacs

I can set a router to authenticate via a ssh public-key with:

```
ip ssh pubkey-chain
 username admin
  key-string
   <ssh-pub-key>
  exit
 exit
```

Is it possible to do something similar with Cisco ACS, to enable a public key to be trusted for ssh across a whole set of devices that are already configured for TACACS+?

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: well, it was a 'looks like' not 'absolutely' does not, (ie lack of positive evidence of this function, vs positive evidence of the lack of function) so I figured I'd leave the question open a couple of days with your bounty to see if any more details came out.

Comment: I don't use tacacs and don't have any version of ACS running, so I cannot say with 100% confidence. The "looks like" is based on researching features of the various versions of ACS, and the lack of documented support in any other tacacs server.

Comment: @RickyBeam I've got a copy of ACS running - but, like you said, I couldn't find anything either - so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like, "No".  There's nothing specific in TACACS+ to transport a certificate exchange, however an ASCII data payload *could* suffice. (the RFC is a decade old) The real question is if ACS has any method to handle it? And that also appears to be "no". The only mention I can find to PKI or certificate based authentication is for EAP-TLS, which is not what you want.

**Update**

I found a single reference in [IOS-XR documents](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/crs/software/crs_r4-2/security/configuration/guide/b_syssec_cg42crs/b_syssec_cg42crs_chapter_01001.html#con_1095059):

> **Note** The preferred method of authentication would be as stated in the SSH RFC. The RSA based authentication support is only for local authentication, and not for TACACS/RADIUS servers.

Comment: That's a shame. You can manage a whole network infrastructure with user/pass, but one would think there would be a PKI structure to do the same. I found http://freeradius.1045715.n5.nabble.com/Is-Centralized-SSH-Public-Key-Authentication-Possible-td2779208.html which seems to say the same: centralized ssh key auth is just not possible (with RADIUS either). This project [openssh-lpk](https://code.google.com/p/openssh-lpk/) seems related,  but it looks like its for centralized ssh to hosts, not devices such as routers/switches.

Comment: There's *one* official answer from the mothership.